# How can I get price information in this html?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want get the name of product and the price in this page, follow my code:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.paodeacucar.com/produto/67746/")
product_html = parser.fromstring(r.text)
name = product_html.xpath("//h2[@class='hidden-xs hidden-sm ng-binding']/text()") price_str =
product_html.xpath("//p[@class='normal-price ng-binding ng-scope']/text()")
```

[Inpector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q27NO.png)

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well from within the browser console: from inspector, right click -> copy as outerHTML.

When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well from within the browser console: from inspector, right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: And please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

(Edited for you)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Selenium since the wesbite uses javascript to display the prices.
To select the price of the product, with Selenium, you'll need something like :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get('https://www.paodeacucar.com/produto/67746/')
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//schema[@itemprop='price']"))).get_attribute("content"))
```